# Unable to run sensu check in a docker-compose context

Tags: docker-compose, sensu

I am dockerizing sensu infrastructure. Everything goes fine except the execution of checks.

I am using docker-compose according to this structure (docker-compose.yml):

```
sensu-core:
    build: sensu-core/
    links:
            - redis
            - rabbitmq
sensors-production:
    build: sensors-production/
    links:
            - rabbitmq
uchiwa:
    build: sensu-uchiwa
    links:
            - sensu-core
    ports:
            - "3000:3000"
rabbitmq:
    build: rabbitmq/
redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server
```

My rabbitmq Dockerfile is pretty straightforward:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get -y install wget
RUN wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
RUN dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb

RUN wget http://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc
RUN apt-key add rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc
RUN echo "deb     http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install erlang rabbitmq-server

CMD /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start && \
    rabbitmqctl add_vhost /sensu && \
    rabbitmqctl add_user sensu secret && \
    rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /sensu sensu ".*" ".*" ".*" && \
    cd /var/log/rabbitmq/ && \
    ls -1 * | xargs tail -f
```

So do the uchiwa Dockerfile:

```
FROM podbox/sensu

RUN apt-get -y install uchiwa

RUN echo ' \
{ \
  "sensu": [ \
    { \
      "name": "Sensu", \
      "host": "sensu-core", \
      "port": 4567, \
      "timeout": 5 \
    } \
  ], \
  "uchiwa": { \
    "host": "0.0.0.0", \
    "port": 3000, \
    "interval": 5 \
  } \
}' > /etc/sensu/uchiwa.json

EXPOSE 3000

CMD /etc/init.d/uchiwa start && \
    tail -f /var/log/uchiwa.log
```

Sensu core runs sensu-server & sensu-api. Here is his dockerfile:

```
FROM podbox/sensu

RUN apt-get -y install sensu

RUN echo '{ \
  "rabbitmq": { \
    "host": "rabbitmq", \
    "vhost": "/sensu", \
    "user": "sensu", \
    "password": "secret" \
  }, \
  "redis": { \
    "host": "redis", \
    "port": 6379 \
  }, \
  "api": { \
    "host": "localhost", \
    "port": 4567 \
  } \
}' >> /etc/sensu/config.json

CMD /etc/init.d/sensu-server start && \
    /etc/init.d/sensu-api start && \
    tail -f /var/log/sensu/sensu-server.log -f /var/log/sensu-api.log
```

sensors-production runs sensu-client along with a dumb metric, here is his Dockerfile:

```
FROM podbox/sensu

RUN apt-get -y install sensu

RUN echo '{ \
  "rabbitmq": { \
    "host": "rabbitmq", \
    "vhost": "/sensu", \
    "user": "sensu", \
    "password": "secret" \
  } \
}' >> /etc/sensu/config.json
RUN mkdir -p /etc/sensu/conf.d
RUN echo '{ \
  "client": { \
    "name": "wise_oracle", \
    "address": "prod_sensors", \
    "subscriptions": [ \
      "web", "aws" \
    ] \
  } \
' >> /etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json

RUN echo '{ \
  "checks": { \
    "dumb": { \
      "command": "ls", \
      "subscribers": [ \
    "web" \
      ], \
      "interval": 10 \
    } \
  } \
}' >> /etc/sensu/conf.d/dumb.json

CMD /etc/init.d/sensu-client start && \
    tail -f /var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log
```

Running
    docker-compose up -d
Everything goes OK. No errors in the logs, I can access the uchiwa dashboard, which shows me the defined client alright (keepalive requests seems to be OK). However, no check is available.

I noticed that no check request / check result is present in the log, as if the sensu server consider there is no check to run. Although, I have no idea why is that.

Could someone tell me what's going on more precisely? Thank you.

Comment: Where is the check supposed to run? In the `sensors-production` container?  You can try running `docker exec -ti <container>` for that container, and running some checks manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check request/result will delivered via RabbitMQ, you can access to http://yourrabbitmqserver:15672 to see the queue and subscribed consumers.
Also make sure your server have some check.json files placed in /sensu/conf.d to schedule checks base on their interval